# Iframe reloads on hover to other componets eg: tooltip

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, iframe

I have used iframe tag to load one of the url, but iframe data reloads every time when i hover to any other component, eg: tooltip, or open any dropdown. It totally refresh the iframe.

HTML Code:

`<iframe scrolling="no" style="border-width:0px; overflow: hidden;" [src]=transform(mapUri)></iframe>`

TS File Code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from "@angular/platform-browser";

export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

mapUri = "https://sub.domain.com/";

constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

transform(url:any) {
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. would be helpful if u could provide a codepen.
2. why not exporting the sanitizing to a pipe?

Comment: Thank @gil, the second option worked for me. Now iframe does not refresh/reload data on hover to any other component or clicking on dropdown. I have done: ```1. ng g pipe safe(on app folder)```, ```2. import and declare safe into test.module.ts``` ```3. <iframe scrolling="no" style="border-width:0px; overflow: hidden;" [src]="mapUri | safe"></iframe>```

Comment: happy to hear it helped, please accept my answer as the solution so others will be able to benefit from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems like the way you handled the iframe src sanitization did one of the following:

1. triggered a rerender of the iframe
2. retriggered the transform function and hence reloaded your iframe
   content

every time you were hovering any other component on the page.

with pipe this unexpected behavior will probably be prevented and also when sanitizing, I find it more suitable to export the functionality to a dedicated pipe so this way you'll be able to reuse it across different components on your app and prevent code duplication.

here's the pipe implementation:

```
@Pipe({ name: 'safeUrl' })
export class SafeUrlPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}
  transform(url: string) {
      return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
  }
}
```